# Global sections of a vector bundle over $OG(2,7)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, vector-bundles, grassmannians, projective-varieties

Let us work over $\mathbb C$, using the Grothendieck projectivization $\mathbb P():=Proj(Sym())$.

Consider a $7$-dimensional vector space $V$ endowed with a symmetric non-degenerate bilinear form $q:V \times V^\vee \to \mathbb C$. We define
$$
OG(2,7):=\{\mathbb P W \subset \mathbb P V: \dim W=2 \text{ and }W \text{is }q-\text{isotropic}\}.
$$
Consider the tautological bundle sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal Q^\vee \to V^\vee \otimes \mathcal O \to \mathcal S \to 0
$$
where $\mathcal Q^\vee$ is the tautological subbundle over $OG(2,7)$. Thanks to the quadratic form, we can define the orthogonal bundle
$$
\mathcal Q^\vee_\perp \to OG(2,7)
$$
that is a rank $5$ vector bundle over $OG(2,7)$ which over a point $[\mathbb P W]$ it puts the vector space
$$
W^\vee_\perp=\{v \in V: q(v,w)=0 \text{ for all }w \in W^\vee\}.
$$
Using the identification given by the bilinear form, $V \simeq V^\vee$ and we can decompose
$$
V^\vee=U \oplus Z \oplus Z'
$$
where $\dim U=1$ and $\dim Z=\dim Z'=3$. In particular, $W^\vee \subset Z$ and $W^\vee_\perp$ is the orthogonal complement. One can show that $U \subset W^\vee_\perp$, essentially by looking at what happens in the even case.

This last fact allow us to write $\mathcal Q^\vee_\perp$ as the central term of a short exact sequence over $OG(2,7)$
$$
0 \to \mathcal O \to \mathcal Q^\vee_\perp \to \mathcal E \to 0
$$
that correspond fiberwise to
$$
0 \to U \to W^\vee_\perp \to W^\vee_\perp/U \to 0.
$$

**Question:** The space of global sections $\Gamma(OG(2,7),\mathcal E)$ corresponds to a representation of $SO(7)$, which one?
I hope that it is the tensor product between $V$ and the $8$-dimensional spin representation.

I think that one should use the Borel-Weyl_bott theorem, by I frankly never see an explicit computation, so a step-by-step resolution would be wonderful.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you defined $OG(2,7)$ as a set or a variety. What do you mean by "a representation of $OG(2,7)$"? Did you mean "a representation of $O(V;q)$" instead, or something like that?

Comment: One can prove that $OG(2,7)$ is the quotient of the orthogonal special group $SO(7)$ by a parabolic subgroup. In particular it is a rational homogeneous projective variety of Picard number 1. By a representation of $OG(2,7)$ I mean a representation of $SO(7)$